# Run jQuery code after AJAX jQuery load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can i run the below code only after the code 1 has load all its content from the external page ?

jQuery Script tried

```
//filters
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    $(".filters li").on("click", function () {
    id = ($(this).data("id")+'').split(',');
    filter = $(this).data("filter");
    $("#hotel-list .box").hide();
    id[0] == "all" && $("#hotel-list .box").show() || id.forEach(function(v){
        $('#hotel-list .box[data-'+filter+'*="'+v.trim()+'"]').show();
    });
    return false;
});
      <!-- Count Star Rating -->
        var two_stars = $("article[data-stars*='2']").length;
        var three_stars = $("article[data-stars*='3']").length;
        var four_stars = $("article[data-stars*='4']").length;
        var five_stars = $("article[data-stars*='5']").length;
        $('.total-three').text(three_stars);
        $('.total-four').text(four_stars);
        $('.total-five').text(five_stars);
        var totals = three_stars + four_stars + five_stars + two_stars;
        $('.totals').text(totals);      
        <!-- Count Board -->
        var board_no = $("article[data-board*='No']").length    
        var board_ro = $("article[data-board*='Room']").length  
        var board_bb = $("article[data-board*='Breakfast']").length;            
        var board_fb = $("article[data-board*='Full Board']").length    
        var board_hb = $("article[data-board*='Half']").length  
        var board_ai = $("article[data-board*='All']").length   
        var board_sc = $("article[data-board*='Self']").length  
        $('.total-ro').text(board_ro);
        $('.total-bb').text(board_bb);
        $('.total-fb').text(board_fb);
        $('.total-hb').text(board_hb);
        $('.total-ai').text(board_ai);
        $('.total-sc').text(board_sc);
        var total = board_ro + board_bb + board_fb + board_hb + board_ai + board_sc + board_no;
        $('.total').text(total);

  //Fix broken images
  fixBrokenImages = function( url ){
    var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var i=0, l=img.length;
    for(;i<l;i++){
        var t = img[i];
        if(t.naturalWidth === 0){
//this image is broken
            t.src = url;
        }
    }
}
 window.onload = function() {
    fixBrokenImages('images/noimg.png');
 }
});
```

And the jQuery AJAX code is:

```
var datastring = location.search; // now you can update this var and use
$("#hotel-list").load("Rezults2.php"+ datastring + " #hotel-list> *");
```

So i need that the 1st codes to be executed only after the 2nd code has done its job ( from 3 to 9 secs )

ANy ideea on this ?

Comment: use call back method of load() function in jquery

Comment: @MarsOne are you seroius ?

Comment: `$("#hotel-list").load("Rezults2.php", function(){ /* do something else. */ })`

Comment: YOU CANT HAVE HTML COMMENTS IN JS

Comment: @john-smith i have html comments in js code wrap and it work,

Answer (score 2):

```
function runThisAfter() {
    var two_stars = $("article[data-stars*='2']").length;
    var three_stars = $("article[data-stars*='3']").length;
    var four_stars = $("article[data-stars*='4']").length;
    var five_stars = $("article[data-stars*='5']").length;
    //etc...
}

$("#hotel-list").load("Rezults2.php", function(){ runThisAfter(); });
```

This will run "runThisAfter()" when load is complete.

Comment: Thanks but if you check that code it does more than load . so i need to have the same functions.

Comment: Finalizing the code is up to you. Your question has been answered: Use the callback-functionality to add code after the first call has completed. You can add your entire first script to the "runThisAfter()", but using "onLoad" and "load" is not needed, nor wanted, since you want to load it in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
   // Your complete function here
});
```

Or in my Case full code:

```
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
        //Count STARS
        var two_stars = $("article[data-stars*='2']").length;
        var three_stars = $("article[data-stars*='3']").length;
        var four_stars = $("article[data-stars*='4']").length;
        var five_stars = $("article[data-stars*='5']").length;
        $('.total-three').text(three_stars);
        $('.total-four').text(four_stars);
        $('.total-five').text(five_stars);
        var totals = three_stars + four_stars + five_stars +
          two_stars;
        $('.totals').text(totals);
        //COUNT BOARD
        var board_no = $("article[data-board*='No']").length
        var board_ro = $("article[data-board*='Room']").length
        var board_bb = $("article[data-board*='Breakfast']").length;
        var board_fb = $("article[data-board*='Full Board']").length
        var board_hb = $("article[data-board*='Half']").length
        var board_ai = $("article[data-board*='All']").length
        var board_sc = $("article[data-board*='Self']").length
        $('.total-ro').text(board_ro);
        $('.total-bb').text(board_bb);
        $('.total-fb').text(board_fb);
        $('.total-hb').text(board_hb);
        $('.total-ai').text(board_ai);
        $('.total-sc').text(board_sc);
        var total = board_ro + board_bb + board_fb + board_hb +
          board_ai + board_sc + board_no;
        $('.total').text(total);
        //Fix broken images
        fixBrokenImages = function(url) {
          var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
          var i = 0,
            l = img.length;
          for (; i < l; i++) {
            var t = img[i];
            if (t.naturalWidth === 0) {
              //this image is broken
              t.src = url;
            }
          }
        }
        window.onload = function() {
          fixBrokenImages('images/noimg.png');
        }
        });
        });
```